# Responsive HTML email - 3 column layout spacing for Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, spacing

I'm trying to perfect a 3 column layout and I'm having some issues with the spacing between the tables but the issue only appears in Outlook 2007,10, 13

Now in everything else (browsers and other clients) I'm able to evenly space the tables to the edge of their container without the last column falling to the next line:

SEE IMAGE:

[image: example of element moving to next line]

You'll notice from the image the second set of columns are what I'm aiming to achieve but without having to drastically reduce the spacing between tables just so it can work in Outlook as this of course affects all the other clients and makes the tables look very close together. (just not close together in Outlook).

Here is the link to the entire HTML:

http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/email.html

Please have a look at the code - what you're going to be looking for specifically are the tables with 190 width and then a comment above a table `<----padding + outlook ----->`

NOTE: you'll notice that the first `<----padding + outlook ----->` table isn't the same and that's because I'm playing around with it to try and find a fix for the issue.

I've also read lost of posts from Email on Acid and other services with lots of notes on outlook bugs etc but I simply can't find a resolution for this!

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: I lose this much space due to the issues in outlook

http://jimharrison.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/space.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your table structure so you have each box contained within a table and each of the 3 tables are contained within a single row separated into separate columns.  Leverage cellpadding on the inner tables And cellpadding on the parent table to achieve the required spacing rather than using an empty space or set dimensions.

Assign dimensions to nothing other than the total width of the parent table.  Make sure you have table, table td:border-collapse:collapse; in your CSS and all your tables are zero'd out with border=0, cellspacing=0, cellpadding=0 (except for wherever you need to adjust the padding.

Place your images and text within td's and nothing else.  If your using a paragraph or header tag remove it.

If you structure your table in this way it won't wrap until you want it to.

Comment: Thanks - this solution does make sense. I was wondering though if maybe outlook had a minimum width for tables or something? I know it does with heights lower than 15 which can be fixed by adding line-height and font-size. Anything similar with width? (I've tried letter spacing).

Comment: As far as I know you should be good with anything (width or height) as long as it's over 3 pixels.  As a general purpose standard for myself, when creating tables strictly for spacing I set the dimensions of the td to 3 pixels and attempt to achieve the sizing I need using the table's cellpadding attribute which will be respected universally.  I usually only create table spacers to separate content vertically though like so <table border="0" cellpadding="11" cellspacing="0"><tr><td height="3"></td></tr></table> <!-- 25pixel vertical space -->

Comment: If your creating a table spacer to separate content horizontally, or vertically for that matter, you should consider whether or not you can achieve the same affect using the surrounding tables cellpadding first.  And if you use the method in my previous comment you don't need to add a gif spacer, no clients as far back as Outlook 07 collapse the tables as I've structured them.

Comment: I see what you're saying - if the styles I'm aiming to achieve are possible with basic HTML over CSS then use HTML.

I'm going to place the tables into columns and apply padding with cellpadding to get it working. Will report back once I finish it!

Comment: Yeah, let me know how it goes.  Sorry I've been so busy I haven't even had a chance to review your code yet but I intend to tomorrow.

Comment: As for emails, or anything for that matter in my opinion, you should attempt to use the most depreciated method possible.  People tend to use new syntax which only ever has limited support when the same affects can be achieved with depreciated tags.. Depreciated just means me me ..cross/backwards compatible

Comment: Ahhhh I thought it meant no longer available or valid. So certain tags  for example that are depreciated in HTML 5 can't be used with the HTML doctype? (or have I got that wrong?)

Comment: EDIT: I meant can't be used with the HTML 5 doctype*

Comment: They can be used they just won't validate properly.  But for an email you should not be using an HTML5 doctype anyway.  The recommended doctype is XHTML1.0 Strict because this will be imposed by Gmail regardless of any other declaration.

Comment: I thought gmail simply stripped out the doctype rather than add it's own. Well that's annoying! Thanks for the tip. I'm going to work on finishing it up today and will report back

Answer (score 1):

I understand you're structuring your tables like so to make it "responsive" so it collapses on mobile browsers

```
<wrapping table><tr>
  <td><table1><padding table><table2><padding table><table3></td>
</tr>
</wrapping table>
```

There is a trick to allow you to force the tables not to wrap by putting them into different columns ie:

```
<wrapping table><tr>
<td><table1></td><td><table2></td><td><table3></td>
</tr>
</wrapping table>
```

and THEN change the `<td>` float property to `float:left` when in a mobile envrionment (using media queries) to let them stack instead.

See tip #5: Floating columns

http://www.creativebloq.com/responsive-web-design/build-responsive-emails-2132830

Comment: Thanks dude - I was going to apply the changes you said as per answer below but wasn't sure how to tackle this in responsive but you answered that too!

Is it possible to mark 2 asnwers as correct? haha :S

Answer (score 0):

One of your padding tables has a width and all the other ones don't. That could possible by the issue.

If that doesn't work, I would suggest containing each table in a table cell "td", to better control their size.

Comment: Yeah the first padding table is different because I was experimenting with altering widths to attempt to get Outlook to respond to different styling but there always seems to be a minimum width of 17px or so.

NOTE: the image doesn't show my issue only my attempts to resolve it - I can get the columns all on one line but as a result don't go to the edge of their container.

I hope this makes sense!