# Mobile not rendering responsive email properly

Tags: css, email, responsive-design

Thanks in advance for any help I get.

This one has truly got me stumped. I had originally built a solid layout which I tested and made sure worked perfectly (which it did in all views). From there I can swap out content whenever I need to if I have to send out a newsletter.

Anyway I've noticed it doesn't always render the same even though it's the same damn template I'm using which I got to work in the first place.

Visit here then click on relevant file:

http://www.jimharrison.co.uk/

single.jpg - shows you how it should look (screenshot taken in browser)

broken.jpg - shows you how it looks on mobile (screenshot taken from our email testing and sending system).

3_col_template.html - is the html itself. Feel free to have a look and dive into the code.

NOTE: like I said before SOMETIMES it works and sometimes it renders like this! What the hell is going on?!

(We have also tested this on Iphone 5 and again sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't).

Currently I'm thinking it's a result of this email testing and delivery software we're using but again I've no idea. The only thing I've changes since it lasts work is the content (replacing placeholder content with actual content).

EDIT: these issues happen on iphones 4-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix my issue I placed tables next to each other rather than have them separated by tds.

To solve table spacing issues that I was getting in Outlook I applied 'mso' styling to target Outlook.

In the style section I used this:

table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;}

You can also inline this and apply to other elements (such as tds) to reset the layout as much as possible in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Try using device-width media queries as well as screen.

Answer (score 0):

Email client's can be a pain to work with, desktop through mobile, I recommend a framework [called Ink](http://zurb.com/ink/) to take the pain out of development and improve compatibility across devices.

If such a framework is too bloated for your scenario, then [read this article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/responsive/) by Campaign Monitor for responsive email best practices.

A sample media query that should be helpful to you:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* Target mobile devices */
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I've just had a chance to test this and unfortunately no luck. I did download the ink boilerplate and have used some of the stying in my html/css. Strangely enough the responsiveness of it works fine in Firefox in my email previewer just not in webkit. I have identified the problem and it's my 3 column <td> wrapping around my tables. (<td><table<td><table><td><table>). 

Having to go <table><table><table> now which is fustrating as it works responsively but not perfectly in outlook.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238755/responsive-html-email-3-column-layout-spacing-for-outlook